# E.split not a function error when attaching date as data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, split

We've got a problem where jquery is giving us an "E.split is not a function" error when we try to attach a date as data to a DOM object.

We are creating our date as follows:

```
new_end_date = new Date(start_time_date);
new_end_date.setMinutes(start_time_date.getMinutes() + service_duration);
```

Then we are using the `.data()` function to attach the data to a dive with the id end_time as follows

```
$("#end_time").data(new_end_date);
```

According to our reading the .data() function should be able to "attach data of any type to DOM elements" (see: http://api.jquery.com/data)

However it causes the split is not a function error.

It works fine if we replace the date reference with a string so it appears to be related to Jquery's handling of the date object.

Thanks for any assistance you can offer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data function expects a key.

```
$("#end_time").data("enddate", new_end_date);
```

or an object (with key/value pairs)

```
$("#end_time").data({ enddate: new_end_date });
```

Comment: Thanks, this was a silly case of me not reading properly.  I saw that you could attach an object, but didn't read that the object had to be a key/value pair.  Doh!

Answer (score 1):

Your using `.data` wrong. your supposed  to store the data under a key. Like

`$("#end_time").data("end-date", new_end_date);`

Then you can call `$("#end_time").data("end-date")` to get that date out again.